# Read a single image to Matlab from a Tiffstack without loading the entire stack

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, parallel-processing, tiff

I need to read images from a large stack of Tiff files while the stack is being updated with additional images. I don't wanna load the stack multiple times for performance issues. Is there a trick do read a single image at a time in Matlab?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.  You have a bunch of tif files, `imread()` accepts the file name of a single tif file as input.  If you just want to read a single image just call `imread` on a single file name.

Comment: by Tiffstack do you mean a multi-tiff file? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @surgical_tubing it is possible to save multiple images in a single TIFF file

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Tiff [class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff-class.html) in Matlab to manipulate a multi-tiff file, i.e. a single tiff file containing many tiff images. Please note that I'm no expert in this regard, but when I first encountered this I was completely lost and after some fooling around with it I could get it to work so I hope it will help you. This should hopefully get you started; and you can easily put this in a loop to select multiple frames form your stack.

In the following code, `TiffName` refers to the name of your multi-tiff file.

```
%// Set up Tiff object in 'read' mode
Stack_TiffObject = Tiff(TiffName,'r');

%// Frame you wish to read                            
FrameToRead = 4;

%// Use setDirectory method to access the image in the stack
Stack_TiffObject.setDirectory(FrameToRead)

%// Read image data
YourImage = Stack_TiffObject.read();                            

%// Close the Tiff object when you're done               
Stack_TiffObject().close
```

Unless I missed something completely obvious that should load only selected frames from your stack.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My "TiffName" is a huge stack of Tiff files which is updated with more images while I'm trying to read individual slices from it and process them. The point is multiple loading of "TiffName" affects my performance. So, I wanna access the required slice without importing the whole stack to Matlab.

Comment: mhh ok I see the problem; unfortunately I don't know how to load part of the stack while it is being constantly updated...I had missed that part sorry